# Values are not getting fetched in admin login process in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have created a controller named Admin.php

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller { 


function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index($msg = NULL) {
     $data['msg'] = $msg;

    $this->load->view('pages/sign-in');

}
 public function process(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('admin/Admin_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->Admin_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
   if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect(base_url().'home');
    }      

}
```

and model is

```
 class Admin_model extends CI_Model
 {
 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
       $this->load->database();
 }
 public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('wc_watchconnect_adminlogin');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'userid' => $row->id,

                'username' => $row->username,
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
}
```

}

one more controller is home

```
class Home extends CI_Controller { 


function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
     $this->check_isvalidated();
}

 public function index(){
    $this->load->view('pages/index');
}
private function check_isvalidated(){
    if(! $this->session->userdata('validated')){
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin');
    }
}
}
?>
```

in this $result is showing null value it is blank while i have username=admin and password=admin in database ... values are not getting fetch in $result pls help me to get rid out of this... thanks in advance

Comment: At where `$result` is showing null??

Comment: i am using if $result == '' then redirect to home page in controller instead of using $msg.... it is going to home page

Comment: And please adopt habbit to accept answer . Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
if($query->num_rows == 1)
```

To

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
```

Add `()` after `num_rows`

Read [num_rows()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-helper-methods)

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    // If there is a user, then create session data
    $row = $query->row();
    $data = array(
        'userid' => $row->id,
        'username' => $row->username,
        'validated' => true
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    return true;
} else {
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can ask your question

Comment: actually to show error message i am using $msg as you can see in controller. When i display $msg in view file it gives an error of undefined variable$msg... here is my view file

Comment: <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/process" method="POST" name="process" >
<?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?> 
<div class="log-input"><div class="log-input-left">   <input type="text" class="user"  name="username" placeholder="username"/></div>
<div class="clearfix"> </div></div><div class="log-input">
<div class="log-input-left">
           <input type="password" class="lock"  name="password" placeholder="password"/>
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
      
      </form>

Comment: @Pardeep better post a new question with new requirement !!