# form validation using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

In this when i submit my form it shows errors first then reload the page and go to index page.. but i want is show only error message not reload page after.. here my controller is

class User extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{

     $this->load->view('index');


}
public function error()
{
    /* Load form helper */ 
     $this->load->helper(array('form'));

     /* Load form validation library */ 
     $this->load->library('form_validation');

     /* Set validation rule for name field in the form */ 
    $form_data = array('brand_name' => $this->input->post('brand_name'), 'your_name ' => $this->input->post('your_name'), 'mobile_no' => $this->input->post('Mobile No.'));         
     if($this->form_validation->run($form_data) == FALSE )
     { 

      echo validation_errors();

     } 
     else 
     { 
       $this->load->view('submit'); 
    } 
}
}
```

and my view file named index.php is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#get').click(function(){
    $.post("<? base_url() . 'user/error' ?>",
    $("form").serialize(),
    function(result) {
    $("#error_message").html(result).appendTo("form"); 
    },"html");
    });    
    });
    </script>
    <form role="form" action="" class="form-inline" name="form" method="POST" id >
    <div id="error_message" style="color:red"></div>

     <?php echo form_open('form'); ?> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Brand Name" name="brand_name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Brand Name'">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" name="your_name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Your Name'">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">                
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" name="mobile_no" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Mobile No'">
            </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">                
                <input type="submit" id="get" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Proceed" ></input>
            </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </form>
```

i just want it shows error message only not reload page after please help... thanks in advance

Comment: i also remove $this->load->view('index'); from if condition in controller but didnt works

Comment: already did that!!!!

Comment: can you pls answr my ques

Comment: No you not accept any answer!!

Comment: Please adopt habit to accept answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218217/values-are-not-getting-fetched-in-admin-login-process-in-codeigniter/38218367#38218367, http://stackoverflow.com/users/6555081/pardeep and http://stackoverflow.com/users/5751525/pardeep

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post form in AJAX so you will need to set the form data manually

Tested with CI 2

```
$form_data = array('brand_name' => $this->input->post('brand_name'), 'your_name ' => $this->input->post('your_name')); // other fields as required for validations
```

And validation for the same would be

```
if($this->form_validation->run($form_data) == TRUE ){
     //validation passed
}else{
     //validation fail
}
```

For CodeIgniter 3, as the Online documentation mentions try https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Validating an Array (other than $_POST)
Sometimes you may want to validate an array that does not originate from $_POST data.

In this case, you can specify the array to be validated:

```
$data = array(
        'username' => 'johndoe',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'passconf' => 'mypassword'
);

$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST) inside your function return